# count variable incrementing once

Tags: python

```
def countDog1(st):
    count = 0
    for word in st.lower().split():
        if word == 'dog':
            count += 1
    return count
```

I want to increment the value of count, but it only works one time.

Comment: Please give an example input

Comment: please make sure your indentation accurately reflects what you actually are using. Also, provide a [mcve]. We don't know how you are running this function, what is the input?

Comment: I assume that you are doing `return count` in the for loop or in if block itself, keep the proper indentation

Answer (score 0):

I assume the unexpected behavior is caused by non-alphanumeric characters in your string:

```
'hello dog dog!'.lower().split()
```

returns

```
['hello', 'dog', 'dog!']
```

And thus "dog" will only be counted once. Here is an example on how to tackle that with `re`:

```
import re

def countDog1(st):
    count = 0
    for word in st.lower().split():
        if word == 'dog':
            count += 1
    return count

print('Function countDog1: ' + str(countDog1('hello dog I am a dog!')))

def countDog2(st):
    count = 0
    st = re.sub(r'([^\s\w]|_)+', '', st)
    for word in st.lower().split():
        if word == 'dog':
            count += 1
    return count

print('Function countDog2: ' + str(countDog2('hello dog I am a dog!')))
```

Output:

```
Function countDog1: 1
Function countDog2: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

The function you wrote in the question seems working. Make sure you indented well the return statment. You probably indented it one level too much in your code.

Comment: As two comments have asked, we need to see the input. It's impossible to say whether or not it works as intended otherwise. (Well, it probably doesn't because they asked a question, but _why_ it doesn't work is a different matter).